# Exportar imagem salva como Varbinary em diferentes formatos

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho algumas imagens no banco de dados SQL Server 2017 que foram gravadas como varbinary. Atualmente já tenho um script que exporta como .jpg, porém me deparei que algumas imagens são na verdade .png ou .bmp.

Há alguma maneira de validar em qual formato a imagem foi salva antes de fazer a exportação?

Segue a função que criei:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION EXPORTAIMAGEM(@IDIMAGEM uniqueidentifier)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
as
BEGIN
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'md c:\EXPORTA';
DECLARE @pctStr INT
DECLARE @image VARBINARY(MAX)
DECLARE @MENSAGEM NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @image= (SELECT DATA FROM Document
              WHERE ID=@IDIMAGEM)
DECLARE @filePath NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @filePath = 'C:\EXPORTA\Imagem_'+ CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),@IDIMAGEM) +'.jpg'
EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @pctStr OUTPUT
EXEC sp_OASetProperty @pctStr, 'Type', 1
EXEC sp_OAMethod @pctStr, 'Open'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @pctStr,  'Write', NULL, @image
EXEC sp_OAMethod @pctStr, 'SaveToFile', NULL,@filePath, 2
EXEC sp_OAMethod @pctStr, 'Close'
EXEC sp_OADestroy @pctStr
SET @MENSAGEM=(SELECT CASE WHEN @IMAGE IS NULL THEN 'Imagem_'+  CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),@IDIMAGEM) +' ERRO! VERIFIQUE SE A IMAGEM EXISTE CADASTRADA NO BANCO DE DADOS!'
    ELSE CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),@IDIMAGEM)+' SUCESSO!'
    END)
    RETURN @MENSAGEM
END
```

Comment: Identificar o formato diretamente no SQL Server, na hora de exportar, não sei se é possível. Após extrair um arquivo png, se você só trocar a extensão ele funciona? Se sim, o que você pode fazer é exportar essas imagens e identificar a extensão com um script utilizando o mimetype daquele arquivo

Comment: Trocar a extensão funciona. Mas como acaba tendo em torno de 10 a 15 mil imagens para exportar fica complicado de se fazer um a um. Estamos migrando de imagens no banco para imagens em pasta em um sistema legado.

Comment: Verificando o mimetype a partir de um script pode te ajudar então